# Xamarin Forms Tabbed Page for Profile Page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabs

I need to make a profile screen for a project I'm working on. One page should have many tabs [exactly like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjUzd.gif)
when i search i found this link and nuget package [link](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs)
I think this is exactly what I was looking for! but there is no example usage and i have no idea how to do it
After including this package in my project, how can I make a screen similar to the one in the picture?

Comment: "no example usage" - the repo you link to has multiple pages of documentation as well as a complete sample project.

Comment: hi jason,
I just started the development when I examined the repo, frankly, I didn't notice the examples, then when I cloned and opened the project, I couldn't manage to run the project. Also, when I just browsed the views, I couldn't realize which sample I wanted because as I said, I just started developing. if you want to help ,guide me, this is what i need @Jason

Comment: SO is not intended to provide step-by-step tutorials for free.  Please read [ask] for guidance on what kind of questions are on-topic.